# ATL how to Convert BSTR* str to registry key.SetValue(LPCTSTR str type

Tags: c++, string, atl, bstr

It's been years since I have done C++ let alone ATL code

I have this method that needs surgical help :(

This is for a mobile app so I don't want to use CString and MFC

I need to convert the BSTR* str to the correct type LPCTSTR for use in the registry Set.Value method

```
STDMETHODIMP CAXSampleCtl::SendMSG(BSTR* str)
{
    CRegKey key;

    key.Create(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("MyKeyName"));

    key.SetValue( str <<<--- nope, _T("MyValueName"));

    key.Flush();

    key.Close();

    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Why not just compile with UNICODE #defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COLE2T` macro is just for you, see [String Conversion Classes and Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> To convert to a BSTR, pass the existing string to the constructor of
>   CComBSTR. To convert from a BSTR, use COLE2[C]DestinationType[EX],
>   such as COLE2T.