# convert BSTR to LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, com, atl

Here is my need

```
BSTR l_strArgs;
LPCWSTR  sth;
//----
//---
OutputDebugStringW(sth);
```

How to convert BSTR to LPCWSTR ?

Is there any header only library that coverts any string type(microsoft) to LPCWSTR type ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ATL how to Convert BSTR\* str to registry key.SetValue(LPCTSTR str type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654998/atl-how-to-convert-bstr-str-to-registry-key-setvaluelpctstr-str-type)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just cover `NULL` scenario and you're good to go

```
BSTR l_strArgs;
LPCWSTR sth = strArgs ? strArgs : L"";
```

As you mentioned ATL in the tag, here is ATL-style one-liner:

```
OutputDebugString(CString(l_strArgs));
```

or, to make sure you are staying in Unicode domain:

```
OutputDebugStringW(CStringW(l_strArgs));
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found this one

```
BSTR l_strArgs;
LPCWSTR  sth;
CString cs(_com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(l_strArg));
sth = cs;
OutputDebugStringW(sth);
```

Answer (score 1):

BSTRs become easier to handle when you use a wrapper like _bstr_t instead. Here's the microsoft documentation on them 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

As you would expect, one of the _bstr_t constructors takes a BSTR parameter. There is also an operator to return a const wchar_t* which you should be able to cast to LPCWSTR.

Hope this helps