# How to display a BSTR value with MessageBox function?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm very new to C++. I use Code::Blocks and I need to show a BSTR value with MessageBox function.

I tried to google this question but did not found a suitable answer.

How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert BSTR to LPCWSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611416/convert-bstr-to-lpcwstr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BSTR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/692a42a9-06ce-4394-b9bc-5d2a50440168) is `wchar_t*`, as far as MessageBox is concerned, so you can pass it directly to MessageBoxW. `MessageBoxW(hwnd,bStrVal,...);`

For `MessageBoxA`, you must convert with `WideCharToMultiByte`.

Suggestion: use always unicode in your apps, never leave it.

Comment: Except that `BSTR` has the weird rule that `nullptr` is a valid `BSTR` (but not a valid parameter to `MessageBox`). A `nullptr` `BSTR` is an empty string.

Comment: if I pass it directly, compiler throws an error "error: cannot convert 'BSTR {aka wchar_t*}' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument '2' to 'int MessageBoxA(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT)'|"

Comment: Edited. @Zurab-D

Comment: with `MessageBoxW` I get what I need, thanks! @Michael Chourdakis

Comment: @Zurab-D The Windows API has two versions, the narrow character set version of the API which takes `char` and the wide character set version of the API which takes `wchar_t`. Enabling the wide character set version requires setting the UNICODE and _UNICODE Preprocessor directives before including `windows.h`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836706/what-are-tchar-strings-and-the-a-or-w-version-of-win32-api-functions

Comment: @RichardChambers or, you can simply call the `A`/`W` functions explicitly and not have to deal with `UNICODE`/`_UNICODE` at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you don't want to do that. Every Windows app should be set to unicode and never get reminded about that again.